# How could I implement this code in Java

Tags: java, python

```
def choose(left_item,index,total):
    if(index==total):
        yield [left_item]
    else:
        for picked in range(1,left_item):
            for i in choose(left_item-picked,index+1,total):
                item=[picked]
                item.extend(i)
                yield item

choose(100,1,5)
```

I have this simple python code, it helps me solve some Combination questions, the choose function would return an generator. But when I implement this in Java, I could only write this kind of code.

```
public List<int[]> choose(int leftItem, int index, int total) {
    List<int[]> l = new ArrayList<>();
    if (index == total) {
        l.add(new int[]{leftItem});
        return l;
    }
    for (int picked = 1; picked < leftItem; picked++) {
        List<int[]> sub = choose(leftItem - picked, index + 1, total);
        for (int[] item : sub) {
            int[] result = new int[item.length + 1];
            result[0] = picked;
            System.arraycopy(item, 0, result, 1, item.length);
            l.add(a);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

The Java version would save all results into a list before return. It's really a while before I get results.

How could I write a Generator version of java code.

Comment: Maybe you could add some examples of desired output?  Combinatorics is a large field, I have no idea what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know Python, but if I'm guessing correctly what it does, and if you're trying to generate all possible 5-element combinations from the range 1..100, I don't see how this code works.  If `picked` is 1, then you call `choose` recursively to get combinations from the range 1..99--which means that you'll generate combinations with two 1's in them.  Unless I've missed something.  Have you verified that your Python code works?

Comment: Why are you using List<int[]> that is a list of int arrays....?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's really a while before I get results"?  It appears to me that the Java code will take a while to get all the results in a list, but then it will dump the entire list almost instantaneously; while the Python code may get the first results more quickly, but should still take about the same _total_ amount of time to get all the results.  Is that the situation?  And if so, why is it important to get the first results quickly?  (Bearing in mind that I don't know Python.)  (If your machine has a small memory I can see how the Java code might be a problem.)

Comment: I want to get a element once it was generated, the java code i wrote would generate all result and return together. In java, it's called iterator, right?@ajb